# Conditional probability of a single random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable

I have a Gaussian random variable $X$ and I have been told to find 
$P[x < a | x > b]$ and $P[|x|>c]$.

1. What does $P[x < a | x > b]$ mean in terms of a single variable?
2. Is $P[|x|>c]$ the same as $-x < c < x$?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

1) $P(X<a|X>b)$ means "the probability of X being less than $a$ given that it is greater than $b$."

This conditional probability must be equal to $P(b<X<a|X>b) = \frac{P(b<X<a)}{P(X>b)}$. (If we already know that $X$ is greater than $b$, we renormalize by the area under the curve to the right of $b$.)

2) Yes, the events are complementary: $P(|X|>c) = 1 - P(|X|<c) = 1-P(-c<X<c)$.

Answer (score -1):

P[x < a | x > b] means to estimate P(xb. So assuming a>b, it equals to P(Xb)/P(x>b) = N-1(b)-N-1(a)/(1-N-1(b))

Similarly P[|x|>c] is P(X<-c or X>c) assuming c>0, which equals to 
N-1(-c)+1-N-1(c)

N-1 is the inverse cdf for normal and the above assumes the sd=1 and mu=0 for your x